# Koszul and quadratic algebras with Gorenstein dimension 2

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

In proposition 2.19. of http://inmabb.criba.edu.ar/revuma/pdf/v48n2/v48n2a05.pdf it was mentioned that a finite dimensional algebra of global dimension 2 is quadratic if and only if it is Koszul.

> Question: Is it more general true that a finite dimensional algebra of Gorenstein dimension two is quadratic if and only if it is Koszul?

Here the Gorenstein dimension of an algebra $A$ is the injective dimension of the regular module $A$ (so that the global dimension coincides with the Gorenstein dimension in case the global dimension is finite, thus the question is is more general than the statement in 2.19.).

Comment: I think the answer is negative: Take a preprojective algebra of Dynkin type A and tensor it with a Koszul algebra of global dimension two. The result is an algebra  of Gorenstein dimension two which should not be Koszul.